# Redirection with parameters in Spring MVC + Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, parameters

I'm developing an app with Spring MVC + Spring Security 3.1 and my app is called through a certain URL that contains a parameter that is a XML file as a string.

I'm developing on a test-environment so I built a test controller and I do:

```
String parameter = "<Usuario>\n\t<ID>primaria</ID>\n</Usuario>";
return "redirect:/autenticacion/primaria?parametro=" + parameter;
```

And I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid characters (CR/LF) in redirect location
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    org.springframework.security.config.debug.DebugFilter.doFilterInternal(DebugFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

What can I do to simmulate it?

EDIT: I changed the actual parameter content. The thing is that I can't delete the \t and \r characters as that parameter is generated by an external app, so I have to "accept" a parameter containing \r and \t... how can I do that?

Comment: Can I suggest you change the summary and tags of this question (it is about Spring MVC redirects, but not Spring Security really)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I found a workaround...

I've built a filter that captures the "conflictive" calls and replaces the '\r' characters with '\0' characters and it works! Spring Security doesn't complain :)

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String incomingUrl = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        // Se comprueba si la url original tiene caracter de retorno de carro
        if (incomingUrl.indexOf('\r') >= 0) {
            //Sustituye todos los caracteres retorno de carro por caracter vacío.
            String newUrl = incomingUrl.replaceAll("\r", "");
            //Asigna una nueva url a la petición.
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher(newUrl);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        //Sique adelante la cadena de filtros.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: This was never a Spring Security issue, and I doubt if this is necessary since a url cannot contain those characters.  And this filter doesn't address the original problem with the @Controller, unless I misunderstood (quite possible).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a question of encoding, so you could do that manually yourself.  But Spring will add Model attributes to the redirect URI by default so you could probably just do this

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String handle(Model model, ...) {
    ...
    String parameter = "<Usuario>\n\t<ID>primaria</ID>\n</Usuario>";
    model.addAttribute("parametro", parameter);
    return "redirect:/autenticacion/primaria";
}
```

Comment: or `return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/autenticacion/primaria"), "parametro", parameter);`

Comment: The thing is that your suggestions could work for my test controller but... what would happen in the production environment when the real external app calls my app with the parameter with \n\t characters?

Comment: It would have to encode them. All languages have HTTP and URL libraries that provide encoding features. Command line tools like curl would do the same.

Comment: Yes but... it's a 3rd party app... I don't controll it, I don't develop it and I can't tell them to modify their libraries :S