# How to redirect in Spring WebMVC use JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

In controller I need redirecting to `http://www.example.com/test?params={key1:val1}` I do this:

```
return "redirect:http://www.example.com/test?params={key1:val1}"
```

but get an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for
>   key 'key1:val1'

How to redirect with JSON object?

Comment: Looks like encoding issue, Check out this.
   
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564692/redirection-with-parameters-in-spring-mvc-spring-security

Comment: pff, thanks, it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect based on JSON payload only, if you want that kind of behavior just send Http code or unique data to your front-end which will indicate that a redirect should be made, and do your redirect from the front-end.